# Zend Framework: changing color of string in view

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

I want to set color for specific string in ZendFrame work, is it the best way?

**View:**

```
.not-found{color : red;}
    <?php 
        echo '<div class="not-found">';
        echo $this->not_found;
        echo '</div>';
    ?>
```

**Controller:**

```
$this->view->not_found='no result';
```

Comment: Yes, the best way is to use css

Comment: You can do it in a number of ways, this is one of them and there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: may you explain other ways@vanamerongen

Comment: suggestion -> `<?php if ($notfound): ?><div class="not-found">Not found</div><?php endif ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is correct just wrap your css code within css html markup

Answer (score 0):

If you want your css to work it needs to be in a css file linked to the view or in a style like :

```
<style>
  .not-found{color : red;}
</style>
```